# Не отображается debug панель в yii2 advanced

Tags: php, yii2, отладка

в /frontend/config/main-local.php

есть код

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['мой ип'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['мой ип'],
    ];
}
```

в index.php раскоментированно

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
```

Но панель все равно не отображается, может кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

У меня обычно такие настройки в конфиге

```
'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
```

А в индексном так

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

Никогда никаких пробелам не было с панелью дебага.

**Но это только для локального использования!**

Comment: а у меня удалённый сервер, но ип я прописал, пробывал * . Тоже не работает